# Calling StartXpsPrintJob1()

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I'm trying to use the [`StartXpsPrintJob1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/xpsprint/nf-xpsprint-startxpsprintjob1) API in C#.

However, I couldn't find any information about it using Google. This method is not listed on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

Seems I have to translate the C++ code, including classes and interfaces, into C# and use some kind of `dllimport`? Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge about C++.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Yes, quite unlikely you'll find any sample.  This api is wrapped [by the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-programmatically-print-xps-files).

Comment: There is a XpsPrint.dll that you can reference it to your project ..[also check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374565(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried to add reference of `XpsPrint.dll` but it said invalid assembly, then i try to use `TlbImp` to wrap it, still no luck, it said `XpsPrint.dll is not a valid type library`

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks i'll give it a try, just curious about the efficient improvement of `StartXpsPrintJob1` between `StartXpsPrintJob`

Comment: If you are curious about an obscure detail of the XPS printing api then it is best to ask a question about it.

Comment: Use swig tool to generate API from c++ dll code http://www.swig.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems I have to translate the C++ code, including classes and interfaces, into C# and use some kind of dllimport?

You can save time and effort and use a tool named [SWIG](http://swig.org/), ([Sourceforge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/)) to generate c# code that generate  dllimport.

**How to use:**

- Download  [SWig for windows](https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/swig/swigwin/swigwin-3.0.12/swigwin-3.0.12.zip)
- Create c++ header file that represent [StartXpsPrintJob1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/xpsprint/nf-xpsprint-startxpsprintjob1) , name the file xpsheader.h
- create interface file e.g example.i

  ```
  %module example
   %{
   /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
   #include "xpsheader.h"
   %}

   /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
   %include "xpsheader.h"
  ```
- Run the command:

  swig -csharp example.i

The tool generate punch of files with one file named examplePINVOKE.cs

In fact, it is important to know that SWIG is a fairly complete C++ compiler with support for nearly every language feature. This includes preprocessing, pointers, classes, inheritance, and even C++ templates. SWIG can also be used to package structures and classes into proxy classes in the c# target language---exposing the underlying functionality in a very natural manner.

Answer (score 1):

The error "invalid assembly" is would probably occur if you tried to import XpsPrint.dll into your project as a .Net library: it's actually a "native code" library :(

In theory, you should be able to copy/paste this example into a new MSVS/C# project:

- [How to: Programmatically Print XPS Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-programmatically-print-xps-files).

You'll notice that it just "prints" - it doesn't use any XPS-specific APIs.

If that doesn't work for you, this link might also help:

- [Programmatically print an XPS file to a physical printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311910/programmatically-print-an-xps-file-to-a-physical-printer)

Finally, please note in the Microsoft documentation:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686814(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> [The XPS Print API is not supported and may be altered or unavailable
>   in the future. Client applications should use the Print Document
>   Package API instead.]